# how do I extract specific paragraphs from a text using vim?

Tags: vim, text, extract

I am trying to extract test from a huge file containing text in this format, multiple times

```
CL blahblahblah  
SP blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah  
DE blahblahblahblahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah   
   blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah  
AB blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah 
   blahblahblahblahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah
   blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah    
   blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah   
C1 blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah 
   blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah   
   blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah 
   lahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah 
RP blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah
   blahblahblah blahblahblah  
EM blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah  
NR blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah  
TC blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah 
   blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah  
Z9 blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah  
PU blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah  
PI blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah
```

I am only interested in entries beginning with C1, AB, TI, but sometimes these are spanning multiple lines, and the XX tag lines that are following them are not always the same. Is there an easy way to keep only these entries?
So my remaining text should be like this:

```
TI blahblahblah  
AB blahblahblah b lah blahblah blah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah     
C1 blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah  
   blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah  
   blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah 
TI blah blah blah blah blah blah  
AB blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblahblahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah   
   blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah  blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah 
   blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah 
C1 blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblahblahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah
```

and so forth..

thanks very much!

Comment: you might consider writing a full out script to parse this (perl?) -- also in response to your other comments (_'trying for 3 days straight!'_ and _'always ... one file ... wrong'_)

Comment: I wish I knew how.. I m no programmer, I am now learning a little bit of python, but I don't yet have the skills to do that kind of thing..

Comment: :( sorry sehe, I am truly thankful for your answer! I gave the check to benoit because he had to tolerate me longer (in a chat as well). But yes, now both answers work correctly, I'm more in love with vim than ever, and more in love with this community and platform (if it can be called that)

Comment: that's ok. By now the votes have leveled out, which is ok given the three good answers. My preference, to be honest, was with the awk approach (because it expresses intent). Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do:

```
:$put='X' | 1,$-1g/^\(\s\|C1\|AB\|TI\)\@!/   ,/^\S/-d
:$d
```

This will do the following:

- Insert a line containing “X” at the end
- for each line except the last one (`1,$-1`), if it starts with nonspace and does not start with C1, AB or TI (`g/pattern/`), delete (`d`) till next line not starting with space `,/pattern/` not included (`-` which is short for `-1`)
- remove line “X” at the end

In order to try if you're using Gvim:

- copy this code to your clipboard
- in Gvim run `:@+` (which plays Ex commands from the + register that is linked to the clipboard).

What I got:

```
AB blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah 
   blahblahblahblahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah
   blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah    
   blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah   
C1 blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah 
   blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah   
   blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah 
   lahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah
```

Comment: @sranky: Me too. Do your lines start with spaces? Did you type it exactly as presented? it works on my machine perfectly with the given example.

Comment: well, if they have one of the tags it's .e.g AB_blahblah, otherwise it's three spaces ___ and then the text

Comment: @sranky: did you try using that `:@+` method? gvim or vim?

Comment: do I copy paste all of the code in one go? and, do i include the dollar signs?? (sorry about the noobness)

Comment: aha! ok, got the $ sign. The reason it's not working is that the pattern is not found.. I tried with the \v switch, also doesn't work..anything else I can try, settings-wise?

Comment: Either you type inside vim exactly what is presented, including the colon and dollars. Either you copy to the clipboard exactly that code, then go inside vim in normal mode, and press `:@+` and return, but that method will only work inside gvim, not vim.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7732/discussion-between-benoit-and-sfranky)

Comment: @Benoit +1 for the effort (and the `:@+` trick, I'm going to use that). Could you be running into the same anomaly as I have found?

Comment: @sehe: I thought `:norm! /pat` must always end with validating the pattern with enter… Alternative to those `^M`s is `:exec "norm ...\<CR>"`. The problem I had here is that strangely enough `[^[:space:]]` does not work on OP's vim version, but `\S` does.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
:let @a="" | g/^\v<(C1|AB|TI)>/norm! "Ay/^\S^M
```

**EDIT** Windows-specific: you need to add a 'return' to that line, type `^M` as <kbd>C-q</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> (or `C-v` if you aren't using Windows or your vimrc doesn't set `behave mswin`)

Gets the lines into register `"a`. To replace the buffer with those lines:

```
:%d | put a
```

Or, put it into a new buffer:

```
:new | put a
```

Comment: is theere something wrong with my setup or what? this doesn't work either.. I can see there is some work going on because the cursor lands at the last C1 entry, but register a is empty..

Comment: nope this doesn't work either. reg a is always empty.. could there be something different about my settings?

Comment: sorry, it's 7.3, but I may have an overloaded (with half nonsense commands) vimrc file.. there's something wrong with my regexs I think.. what should be the default regex state when the \v is not used within the command?

Comment: (it worked, see my comment next to your comment on my original question)

Comment: @sfranky: cheers. I'm cleaning up my comment thread so the future visitors won't have to read confusing comments :)

Answer (score 3):

### `awk` solution:

```
awk '
BEGIN{
    tags["C1"]
    tags["AB"]
    tags["TI"]
}
{
    match($0, /^\w+/)
    if(RSTART)
        t=substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
}
t in tags' input.txt
```

#### Translate to vim command:

```
:g/^/let t=matchstr(getline('.'), '^\w\+') | if !empty(t) | let tag=t | endif | if index(['C1', 'AB', 'TI'], tag)==-1 | d | endif
```

Comment: I like it. And that's saying a lot from someone who hates awk in general

Answer (score 2):

This appears to work, but it leaves a blank line at the end of the file.

```
:%s/\v^(C1|AB|TI|\s)@!\_.{-}\n(C1|AB|TI|$)@=//
```

This regex makes use of a few tricky features, I'll try to explain.

- `\v` says the pattern is "very magic", just lets us skip backslashes in a few places.
- `^(C1|AB|TI|\s)@!` matches any line that doesn't start with the target tags or whitespace.
- `\_.` matches any character including newlines.
- `{-}` matches the previous atom as few times as possible (non-greedy).
- `\n` matches the end of a line.
- `(C1|AB|TI|$)@=` matches the target tags or the end of the line (for the end case) with zero width.

The result with your test input is this:

```
AB blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah
   blahblahblahblahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah
   blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah
   blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah
C1 blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah
   blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah
   blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah
```

Answer (score 0):

another awk onliner:

```
awk -F' |\t' '{if($1)f=$1~/CI|AB|C1/?1:0}f' yourFile
```